# MonadBaseControl laws

Tags: haskell

The [`MonadBaseControl` class](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-control-1.0.2.3/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Control.html#t:MonadBaseControl) offers very few laws. To get [something I want](https://github.com/ekmett/free/issues/193), I need one more:

```
forall f q. f <$> liftBaseWith q
  = liftBaseWith $ \runInBase -> fmap f (q runInBase)
```

My extremely vague intuition suggests this is natural (in some sense) and that it might even follow from some combination of the `Functor` laws, parametricity, and the documented `MonadBaseControl` laws. Is this so? If not, are there any "reasonable" instances that disobey the law?

Note: I've also asked an abbreviated version of this question [as a GitHub issue](https://github.com/basvandijk/monad-control/issues/48).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's an immediate consequence of the free theorem of the type of `liftBaseWith`.

A simplified version of the "free theorem theorem" which is sufficient to generate a version of such a free theorem is:

Any function `f :: forall a. F a -> G a` where `F` and `G` are functors, satisfies, for any types `a`,`b`, and any function `phi :: a -> b`,

```
fmap phi . f = f . fmap phi  -- simplified "free theorem" for f
```

(in other words, that equation holds whenever it typechecks.)

I don't have a proof offhand, but I'd be extremely surprised if there is a counterexample.

#### Application

In this case `f` is `liftBaseWith`, where the functors are

```
F a = RunInBase m b -> b a  -- F = ReaderT (RunInBase m b) b
G a = m a
```

Apply both sides of the "free theorem" above to `q`, unfold the definition of `fmap` for `ReaderT`:

```
(fmap phi . liftBaseWith) q = (liftBaseWith . fmap phi) q
fmap phi (liftBaseWith q) = liftBaseWith (fmap phi q)
fmap phi (liftBaseWith q) = liftBaseWith \run -> fmap phi (q run)
```

#### Relevant literature

As a starting point to read up on the topic, there's of course the paper *Theorems for free!* by Philip Wadler, and another closely related one [*Free theorems involving type constructor classes*](https://www.janis-voigtlaender.eu/papers/FreeTheoremsInvolvingTypeConstructorClasses.pdf) by Janis Voigtlander.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more explicitly how that theorem applies here?

Comment: I added an explicit derivation

Comment: Many thanks! I didn't think to reframe the type as `ReaderT`; that makes perfect sense now. I still don't feel like I *really* understand this stuff, but at least I can follow it.

Comment: The "free theorem theorem" is a consequence of parametricity and indeed always holds under the standard  assumptions (the code must treat all types as opaque, no side effects, pure functions, etc.)